# Calling mysql procedure in python with parameter and getting errors

Tags: procedure, pymysql

I use pymysql to connect to db. Here is the way I call the procedure.

cur.execute("call delete_shop_tables(?,?,?,?,?)", args)

The procedure expects 5 string variables.

args has five string variables in an array (args = ["one","two","three","four", "five"])

I get the following errors when the above line is executed.

TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

What could I be missing?

Comment: This is mysql db.

Answer (score 0):

try  `call delete_shop_tables(args)`

This is the right way to call procedures.

Comment: Thanks, but as I stated earlier, this is from python using pymysql.

Answer (score 0):

It's a db we recently inherited. Once I collated the columns in WHERE clause to match with the collation what's in the column definition, it all worked.

Answer (score 0):

I believe in pymysql the argument placeholder is `%s`, not `?`. Try this

```
cur.execute("call delete_shop_tables(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)", args)
```